# What is the correct approach to write multiple small pieces to a temp file in c, in multithreads?

Tags: c, multithreading, fwrite, read-write

I am simulating multithreads file downloading. My strategy is in each thread would receive small file pieces( each file piece has **piece_length** and **piece_size** and **start_writing_pos** )

And then each thread writes to the same buffer. How do I realize it ? Do I have to worry about collisions ?

//=================== follow up ============//

so I write a small demo as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){


 char* tempfilePath = "./testing";
 FILE *fp;
 fp = fopen(tempfilePath,"w+");//w+: for reading and writing 
 fseek( fp, 9, SEEK_SET);//starting in 10-th bytes
 fwrite("----------",sizeof(char), 10, fp);
 fclose(fp);
}
```

And before execution I let content in "./testing" to be "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", after I do the above I get "^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@----------" I wonder where is the problem then ....

Comment: First you should allocate the whole file size. But then why would there be any collisions, if your parameters are correct?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am worrying if one file can be opened and written asynchronously by many threads.

Comment: @yuan, an alternative architecture is a single thread using epoll() or select() to block on all your socket connections. Threads are an overhead. Also you are assuming that multiple threads each reading from a single socket is faster. It probably isn't. Your Ethernet/WiFi will force the data to arrive on your sockets sequentially; it cannot arrive simultaneously. This means that your threads will never actually run in parallel, because only one of them will be receiving data at any time. So you may as well not have them in the first place.

Comment: @bazza this sounds promising and simpler, has anyone done that before ? I just want to make sure the feasibility though I like the idea of trying things, because I have a deadline and cannot try multiple ways within the given time window.

Comment: Also, any comments on this approach: each small piece is written as a separate file with file_name + ".temp" + pieceIndex .... After I receive all of them I reorder the whole thing ?

Comment: @yuan, If you've not used select() or epoll() before then I suggest you stick with the threads if that's how you have started. Reason why: to get performance using select() you have to read whatever bytes have arrived, then call select() again to see from which socket more can be read. If the bytes read so far from a socket is not a complete file piece you have to store it until the rest arrives. That can get complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Do what most torrent clients do. Create a file with the final size having an extension `.part`. Then allocate non-overlapping parts of the file to each thread, who shall have their own file-descriptors. Thus collisions are avoided. Rename to final name when finished.

Comment: No.  Collisions are not avoided if multiple threads use the same `FILE` structure.

Comment: When I wrote the answer, the question did not mention any FILE structures. And I explicitly mentioned the threads need their own file descriptors. So each needs to open the file for itself.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to use a mutex, you can't use `fwrite()`.  `FILE *`-based IO using `fopen()`, `fwrite()`, and all related functions simply isn't reentrant - the `FILE` uses a SINGLE buffer., a SINGLE offset, etc.

You can't even use `open()` and `lseek()/write()` - multiple threads will interfere with each other, modifying the **one** offset an open file descriptor has.

Use `open()` to open the file, and use `pwrite()` to write data to exact offsets.

[`pwrite()` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pwrite):

> pwrite() writes up to count bytes from the buffer starting at buf to
>   the file descriptor fd at offset offset. The file offset is not
>   changed.